# cvSaveImage() проблема с сохранением изображения

Tags: java, javacv

Здравствуйте. Использую JavaCV. 
В ходе работы программы ей нужно сделать фотку с вебки и сохранить ее в папку, созданную программой на рабочем столе. 
Путь к этой папке прописывается так :

```
public static String webcamPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/folder/webcam.png";
```

Изображение сохраняется так :

```
FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0);
    try {
        grabber.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        while (true) {
          IplImage  img = grabber.grab();
            if (img != null) {
                cvSaveImage(webcamPath, img);
        grabber.stop();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Так вот, вебкамера запускается, но фотография не сохраняется, выкидывая этот экспешн :

```
com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber$Exception: videoInput is null. (Has start() been called?)
```

Есть ли другие способы сохранить IplImage в папку на рабочем столе? 
И да, если прописать в пути к изображению любую другую папку не на рабочем столе, (например, сохранять на диск D), то все работает

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Приложите в вопросе реализацию метода csSaveImage и как создается папка, которая создается программой на рабочем столе